# Asp.net website deployed to windows azure not reading the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure

I deployed an asp.net website to windows azure with an SQL server express database instance from visual studio. The website works fine and I can browse between pages BUT the web pages are NOT READING THE DATABASE.

This is my webconfig file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDBConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:jpla04vr2g.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;User Id=myUser@jpla04vr2g;Password=myPass" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

The web site is running fine but is not reading from the database which is also in windows azure deployed at the same time with website in the app data.

The following is the code to login that I use to login. This code was working fine before deployment when the connection string was pointing to the local database in the app data folder:

```
try
{
    string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    connection = new SqlConnection(con);
    command = new SqlCommand("SELECT AdminId, Firstname, Lastname, Username FROM ADMINISTRATOR WHERE  (Username=@UN OR Email=@EM) AND AdminPassword=@AP");
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UN", (string)txtUserEmail.Text );
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EM", (string)txtUserEmail.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AP", FixanythingSecrecy.HashPassword(txtUserPassword.Text));
    command.Connection = connection;
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            Session.Add("AdminId", reader["AdminId"]);
            Session.Add("Firstname", reader["Firstname"]);
            Session.Add("Lastname", reader["Lastname"]);                        
        }
        Response.Redirect("companies.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
         lblStatus.Text = "User name or password incorrect.";
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     Response.Redirect("ErrorPage.aspx");
}
finally
{
    command.Connection.Close();
    connection.Dispose();
    command.Dispose();
}
```

I get an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
>   Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Why do you say seems like, and then later say it's not? Where is your code that reads from the database? You need to provide more detail in your question.

Comment: You can debug this faster if you point your local version to the live SQL Azure DB (so you don't have to keep re-deploying). Also check in the portal  (SQL, Configuration) that you have ticked 'Allow Azure Services'.

Comment: I have done that. My local project in visual studio is pointing to the live SQL Azure DB but it's not working. if I make it point to the local DB in the app data folder it's working fine.

Comment: Now that you have added the error message and relevant code, I have voted to re-open. Please realize that you should include that information from the start next time. When you go into the Azure portal, are you sure you got the right connection string? When I look at one of my in Azure, it has some more stuff: `Server=tcp:mydb.database.windows.net,1433;Database=MyDB;User ID=masonsa@mydb;Password={your_password_here};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;`